# tab bar style resets after presenting a modal with navigation controller

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I want a transparent black theme throughout my iOS app on both navigation bars, tab bars, and toolbars (I use all 3), and I have this set up through storyboards. I have a subclassed tabbar controller that presents a sign up modal with a navigation controller programmatically as follows:

```
    UserSignUpViewController *userSignUpViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UserSignUpViewController"];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:userSignUpViewController];

    userSignUpViewController.delegate = self;
    navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

this is called in my subclass tabbars view did appear, so I can see that my tabbar shows up as translucent black before this animates up modally. when I dismiss this sign up navigation controller, the tabbar reverts to "opaque" meaning solid white. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

The tab/navigation bar tint colors that I set in my appdelegate persist but the translucent styling of the bars gets reset for some reason. I should add that if I don't display the sign up view controller (user is already signed in), then the tab bar is the correct styling. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It could be because you are calling it in `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.